# Firemonkey: receiving images from other apps under Android by using intents

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to receive images from other apps under Android. Therefore I'm using an intent.

I'm able to get the uri of the image, but how can I access the image with this uri?

`imageUri := Data.getData;`

The uri has e.g. the following value:

`content://com.sbh.factu_App.fileprovider/external_private_files/Download/myimage.jpg`

If I'm testing to access this file with `fileexists(JStringToString(imageUri.toString))` the function returns false.
So I think I have to convert the uri to a physical address. But how can I do so?

Here is my IntentHandler:

```
function TForm1.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
  filename: STRING;
  mytype  : STRING;
  imageUri: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then
  begin
    Memo1.ClearContent;

    if Assigned(Data) then
    begin
      mytype := JStringToString(Data.getType);
      memo1.Lines.Add('Intenttype: '+mytype);
      if mytype.StartsWith('image/') then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Append('is image');

        imageUri := Data.getData;
        Memo1.Lines.Append('URI: '+JStringToString(imageUri.toString));
        filename := JStringToString(imageUri.toString);
        Memo1.Lines.Append('filename:'+filename);

        if fileexists(filename) then
          image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(filename)
        else
          Memo1.Lines.Append('file doesn''t exists');
      end;
    end;

    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use filename := JStringtoString(imageuri.getPath) instead of .tostring to receive the path. However, you might not be allowed to access the file depending on the Android version you are adressing.

Comment: Hi Andre,thank you for your reply. As you suspected, I don't have permission to read the file. So unfortunately it doesn't work that way.